# What are set_xlim() and set_ylim() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

Here is the question about applying some limits on x and y axis of the canvas. 
I have found the function for limits but I am not getting their purpose. What are they used for?

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax0 = fig1.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.2,0.5,.4,.4])
ax0.set_xlabel('X')
ax0.set_ylabel('Z')
ax1.set_xlabel('X')
ax1.set_ylabel('Z')


#problem Area
ax1.set_ylim(30,50)
ax1.set_xlim(20,22)


ax0.plot(x,z)
ax1.plot(x,y)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The command is self-explanatory

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html

Answer (score 0):

You can think of set_xlim() and set_ylim() as *zoom* or *area of interest* methods.  See, for example the dataset below:

[image: Plain plot]

Most points are valued around 50, with two outliers; one at 200 and the other at 2.  Depending on your analysis you may want to disregard the outliers.  The easiest way to do that is to use set_ylim around the values of interest:

[image: Plot with both ylim]

While it's hard to tell the values for point 5 and 8, it's a lot easier to see the relative difference between the other points.

That is a valid use for that visualization, though often it is used to present differences as bigger than they actually are, for people that cannot properly read graphs (election polls are often shown this way).

On the x axis, you may want to select just part of your data for presentation (that's very common with time data).

[image: Plot with both xlimits, then with both xlim and ylim]

Here, the second plot uses both xlim and ylim.  That's because when using the xlim, the graph is still using the full data ylim (0-200), which makes it hard to see the difference between the data points.